# how to get the count of similar unique node names in a xml in java where i dont know my node names i just give XML as input

Tags: java

Currently i have a XML which has many nodes in which some nodes are same i want to get the count of those same unique nodes . But i don't know how many nodes are there like that i'm just giving a XML as input.

For ex: Here you can see a sample XML where there are 3 Nodes with Name "Staff" like this i will have many similar nodes which i don't know since i give only my XML as a input so i want the count and name of each of this unique node.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<company>
    <staff id="1" name="test"/>
    <staff id="2" name="test2"/>
    <staff id="3" name="test3"/>
</company>
```

Currently i Have written my code till here to get the total node names present in the XML and its count. After that to get the similar nodes count and its name how to do it i'm stuck Please help me experts

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

/**
 *
 * @author herve
 */
public class XMLNodeCount
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        //String xml = "D:\\Honeywell_Docs\\Canada_Deconsolidation\\Input_Split_xml\\Source\\51090323-005_low_level.xml";
        File fXmlFile = new File("D:\\\\Honeywell_Docs\\\\Canada_Deconsolidation\\\\Input_Split_xml\\\\Source\\\\51090323-005_low_level.xml"); 
        Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse( (fXmlFile));
        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("*");

        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println("name  is : "+nl.item(i).getNodeName()  );
        }

        System.out.println(" Total Node count is : "+nl.getLength() );
    }
}
```

Comment: Start by showing what is the output you want. "Similar unique" doesn't make any kind of sense.

Comment: what is the expected output for above xml?

Comment: Current output is coming in this format.

name  is : PSOccurrenceThread
name  is : PSOccurrenceThread
name  is : ipem_MetaData
name  is : Fnd0GeneralAudit
 Total Node count is : 97144

But i want it like this   
name is : Fnd0GeneralAudit =1
name  is : PSOccurrenceThread =2

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of streams for this specifically so that we can use the 'groupingBy' function.

```
NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("*");

List<String> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
    nodes.add(nl.item(i).getNodeName());
}

Map<String, List<String>> nodeMap = nodes.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::toString));

for (String node : nodeMap.keySet()) {
    System.out.println("'" + node + "' node count : " + nodeMap.get(node).size());
}

System.out.println("  Total Node count is : " + nl.getLength());
```

What this does is push all nodes into the nodes arraylist. We then Stream the nodes and use the groupingBy collector to collect these into a map by distinct key. Then it's a simple case of reading the size of each key in the map because the groupingBy collector will just put each node into a list defined by the key.

Comment: Hi Luke Thanks for the reply, i tried the above code and at this point i  get this error.

Map<String, List<String>> nodeMap = nodes.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::toString));
[The method Grouping By in the type collectors is not applicable for the arguments (string::toString)]

Comment: Streams were introduced in java 8, are you using java 8 to compile your source? If you are using eclipse have you specified the execution environment for java 8?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using `ArrayList`, `HashSet` (for uniqueness) and `Collections.frequency` method  :

```
...
NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
List<String> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
    nodes.add(nl.item(i).getNodeName());
}    
Set<String> uniqueNodes = new HashSet<>(nodes); 
for (String node : uniqueNodes) {
    System.out.println("Occurrences for " + node + " : " + Collections.frequency(nodes, node));
}
```